# Parity transformation on fermionic bilinears

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory, fermions, parity

In the Fermi weak theory we have the fermion bilinears which look like

$$
V_\mu = \bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu\psi
$$
$$
A_\mu = \bar{\psi} \gamma_\mu \gamma_5 \psi
$$

Under a parity transformation

$$
x = (x_0, \vec{x}) \rightarrow \tilde{x} = ( x_0, - \vec{x})
$$

The fields transform like

$$
V^\mu(x) \rightarrow V_\mu(\tilde{x})
$$
$$
A^\mu(x) \rightarrow - A_\mu(\tilde{x})
$$

Why do the contravariant indices transform to covariant indices as well as a coordinate transformation? I thought it would have something to do with the fact that you also have to transform the actual vector components under a coordinate/parity transformation, but I don´t know how to formalize it starting from the explicit form of the bilinears.

Answer (score 1):

A four vector $V^\mu$ has components that we can regard as  $(\rho, {\bf j})$. Under parity the charge $\rho$ does not change, but the current changes sign: $P:{\bf j}\mapsto -{\bf j}$. If the metric signature  is $(+,-,-,-)$ one  way to say this is $V^\mu \to V_\mu$.  If the metric were  $(-,+,+,+)$ we would have to say $V^\mu\to -V_\mu$.

Comment: Why does the sign of the first time component change under parity? If only the spatial part changes sign.

Comment: Also, why does the sign change for $A_\mu$?

Comment: Because with the $(+,-,-,-)$ signature $A^0=A_0$ but $A^i=-A_i$ for $i=1,2,3$.